# Inject Data into HTML and convert HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, html-to-pdf

I am developing a Xamarin forms app. I have a requirement where , From webservice I will be receiving HTML strings with placeholders in json format. I need to replace the placeholders with the appropriate user data and convert HTML to PDF for printing. Any idea on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Generating a PDF sounds more like a job for server-side processing. Why don't you turn it around and send a request to the server for a PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [HTML Renderer for PDF using PdfSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp/)

Here is a basic example method:

```html
public static Byte[] PdfSharpConvert(String html)
{
    Byte[] res = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
        pdf.Save(ms);
        res = ms.ToArray();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @Soufiana Tahiri I am not able to use the package in Xamarin Forms project. will it support xamarin forms project?